# $(a,b,c), (1,1,0) , (0,1,0)$ of $\mathbb R^3$ are linearly independent or not over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra

$(a,b,c), (1,1,0) , (0,1,0)$ of $\mathbb R^3$ are linearly independent or not over $\mathbb R$? ($a,b,c$ are non zero)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\operatorname{span}\{(1,1,0),(0,1,0)\} = \operatorname{span}\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0)\} = \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\times \{ 0\}$, it should be clear that your set is linearly independent if and only if $c\neq 0$. Since that condition is given to be true, the triple is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \det\left(\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \right) = c. $$ So the vectors are linearly independent over $\mathbb{R}$ if and only if $c \neq 0$. The sign of $a$ and $b$ does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

It suffices that $c$ is nonzero to ensure that $\{(a,b,c),(1,1,0),(0,1,0)\}$ is linearly independant.

If $(\lambda,\mu,\nu)$ is such that $\lambda(a,b,c)+\mu(1,1,0)+\nu(0,1,0)=0$, since $c$ is nonzero, $\lambda=0$. Reinjecting this information, you get that $\mu=0$ and then $\mu=0$.